# htaccess not working on ubuntu 12.04 tried everything

Tags: 12.04, apache2, .htaccess

I have frusted doing all things given on web for htaccess get working on ubuntu. But I could not do it. Actually I want to run my `CodeIgniter` app on `LAMP`, its not production server. so in www directory, there could be multiple folders e.g.
www/punepchub

I access url `localhost/punepchub/support/` , it gives 404 error

I want to redirect above link  to `localhost/punepchub/index.php/support/` 
using `htaccess`, following are the contents of htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Where as above mentioned htaccess works perfect on wamp as well as lamp given by godaddy hosting, but it is not working on LAMP server setup on my local ubuntu 12.04 desktop machine
I think apache is not accessing the htaccess file.

I tried following but It didn't worked

1. I have installed lamp using `tasksel`
2. Enabled Rewrite module using command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
3. It displays the module in the list given by command: `sudo apache2ctl -M`
4. Changed `etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file with `AllowOverride All`, Also I did same in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`
5. I have `777` permissions for project folder and files

Also I am confused about Is there any need to create `virtual hosts`, as this is not production server.

Please help me I really don't know how resolve this issue now.

In advance many thanks

Comment: Can you show us the content of you `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Contents of .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_REQUEST=$1 [L]

Comment: I have added details about urls and htaccess file in question please go through it and help me

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the `.htaccess` code, have you tried restarting apache? `sudo apache2ctl restart`.